# Dynamics CRM Email Router not using proxy

Tags: email, proxy, dynamics-crm

I am trying to set up the CRM Email Router to allow our internally hosted ADX Studio Portal to communicate with our externally hosted Dynamics CRM instance.

I have set up the Configuration profile to meet the requirements of our exchange server and created a deployment to an online service provider with the necessary details.

When I attempt to load the data the Email Router Config Manager states that it was unable to retrieve the data:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://CRM.URL/XrmServices/2011/Discovery.svc?wsdl

When we traced the email router with Fiddler the request receives a 407 Proxy Authentication Required message:

> Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are
>   missing."

We have tested the Email Router tool on a personal network (with no proxy requirements) and everything works correctly. However once we are on the internal network which requires the proxy the Email Router Config Manager no longer works.

We have tried using the Dynamics CRM SDK and and the crmsvcutil.exe command line tool but are not sure how it actually tells the Email Router what configuration to use.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to resolve this is to add an authentication bypass on proxy server for the server and/or service account of the email router.

Comment: So it bypasses the proxy completely and has a direct connection?

Comment: Yes, there is no bypass proxy configuration settings in the E-mail Router Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add  section to email router .config file, with proxy settings. This is .net app, so it should pick it up. I never tried this for email router, but might be worth a shot. [look here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Worth a try. I would be interested to know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. We have tried adding these to the config file for the application but it still did not send the credentials required to the proxy..

Answer (score 0):

The answer we received from a MS support technician was "you need to ensure that the proxy will let through (without any modification) any requests to the CRM Web Service”.

We also tried modifying the .config file to include the proxy settings but it didn't work.

We are going to open an official case with MS. Will let you know if we ever get it working.

Comment: Thanks @Phil I feared that would be the case. Look forward to hearing your results.